# Extend runs of certain length

Tags: r, na, run-length-encoding

I have a 640 x 2500 dataframe with numeric values and several `NA` values. My goal is to find a minimum of 75 consecutive `NA` values in each row. For each such run, I want to replace the previous *and* following 50 cells with `NA` values too.

Here's a scaled down example of one row:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 9, 3, 2, 4, 3)
#        run of four NA:  ^   ^   ^   ^
```

I want to detect the run of four consecutive `NA`, and then replace three values before and three values after the run with `NA`:

```
c(1, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, 3) 
#           ^   ^   ^                   ^   ^   ^
```

I have tried to first identify the consecutive `NA`s with `rle`, but running `rle(is.na(df))` gives the error `'x' must be a vector of an atomic type`. This occurs even when I select a single row.

Unfortunately, I do not know what the next steps to take would be in converting the previous and following 50 cells to NA.

Would highly appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if there are more than 75 consecutive NAs?

Comment: Where you wrote "should become `1 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 4 3` .." Shouldn't that be `1 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA *2* 4 3`?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I was meant to add "more than" 75 consecutive NAs, so to clarify - the 50 cells before and after the 75+ NAs must also be converted to NA. Thanks for pointing that out, amended the original post.

David T: Yes, typo on my part - fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you comment that in your data "*some [rows] begin and end with several `NA`s*", hopefully this better represents the real data:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1 1  2  3 NA NA  6  7  8 NA 10
2 1 NA NA NA  5  6  7 NA NA NA
3 1  2  3  4 NA NA NA  8  9 10
```

Let's assume that the minimum run length of `NA` to be expanded with `NA` is 2, and that two values before and two values after the run should be replaced with `NA`. In this example, row 2 would represent the case you mentioned in comment.

First some data wrangling. I prefer to work with a `data.table` in *long* format. With `data.table` we have access to the useful constants `.I` and `.N`, and can easily create run IDs with `rleid`.

```
# convert data.frame to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

# set minimum length of runs to be expanded
len = 2L

# set number of values to replace on each side of run
n = 2L

# number of columns of original data (for truncation of indices)
nc = ncol(d)

# create a row index to keep track of the original rows in the long format
d[ , ri := 1:.N]

# melt from wide to long format
d2 = melt(d, id.vars = "ri")

# order by row index
setorder(d2, ri)
```

Now the actual calculations on the runs and their indices:

```
d2[
  # check if the run is an "NA run" and has sufficient length 
  d2[ , if(anyNA(value) & .N >= len){

    # get indices before and after run, where values should be changed to NA  
    ix = c(.I[1] - n:1L, .I[.N] + 1L:n)

    # truncate indices to keep them within (original) rows 
    ix[ix >= 1 + (ri - 1) * nc & ix <= nc * ri]},

    # perform the calculation by row index and run index
    # grab replacement indices
    by = .(ri, rleid(is.na(value)))]$V1,

  # at replacement indices, set value to NA 
  value := NA]
```

If desired, cast back to wide format

```
dcast(d2, ri ~ variable, value.vars = "value")
#    ri  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
# 1:  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  8 NA 10
# 2:  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 3:  3  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much Henrik, this has perfectly solved the problem. I should have specified the presence of `NA` run lengths at the start and end of the data frame, but this code overcomes that issue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, it's crucial to create minimal examples that still have sufficient complexity - not more, not less ;)

Answer (score 1):

Type coercion worked for me:

```
rle(as.logical(is.na(x[MyRow, ])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this. I wonder if there is a tidier solution than mine though.

```
library(data.table)
df <- matrix(nrow = 1,ncol = 16)
df[1,] <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 9, 3, 2, 4, 3)
df <- df %>%
  as.data.table() # dataset created

# A function to do what you need
NA_replacer <- function(x){
  Vector <- unlist(x) # pull the values into a vector

  NAs <- which(is.na(Vector)) # locate the positions of the NAs
  NAs_Position_1 <- cumsum(c(1, diff(NAs) - 1)) # Find those that are in sequential order
  NAs_Position_2 <- rle(NAs_Position_1) # Find their values

  NAs <- NAs[which(
    NAs_Position_1 == with(NAs_Position_2,
                           values[which(
                             lengths == 4)]))] # Locate the position of those NAs that are repeated exactly 4 times

  if(length(NAs == 4)){ # Check if there are a stretch of 4 WAs
    Vector[seq(NAs[1]-3,
               NAs[1]-1,1)] <- NA # this part deals with the 3 positions occuring before the first NA
    Vector[seq(NAs[length(NAs)]+1,
               NAs[length(NAs)]+3,1)] <- NA # this part deals with the 3 positions occuring after the last NA
  }
  Vector
}
```

```
> df # the original dataset
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1:  1  3  4  5  4  3 NA NA NA  NA   6   9   3   2   4   3
```

```
# the transformed dataset
apply(df, 1, function(x) NA_replacer(x)) %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  data.table::transpose()

V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1:  1  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   2   4   3
```

---

As an aside, the speed is quite good for a hypothetical dataframe sized 640*2500 where a stretch of 75 or more NAs have to be located and the 50 values before and after must be replaced with an NA.

```
df <- matrix(nrow = 640,ncol = 2500)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,] <- c(1:100,rep(NA,75),rep(1,2325))
}

NA_replacer <- function(x){
  Vector <- unlist(x) # pull the values into a vector

  NAs <- which(is.na(Vector)) # locate the positions of the NAs
  NAs_Position_1 <- cumsum(c(1, diff(NAs) - 1)) # Find those that are in sequential order
  NAs_Position_2 <- rle(NAs_Position_1) # Find their values

  NAs <- NAs[which(
    NAs_Position_1 == with(NAs_Position_2,
                           values[which(
                             lengths >= 75)]))] # Locate the position of those NAs that are repeated exactly 75 times or more than 75 times

  if(length(NAs >= 75)){ # Check if the condition is met
    Vector[seq(NAs[1]-50,
               NAs[1]-1,1)] <- NA # this part deals with the 50 positions occuring before the first NA
    Vector[seq(NAs[length(NAs)]+1,
               NAs[length(NAs)]+50,1)] <- NA # this part deals with the 50 positions occuring after the last NA
  }
  Vector
}
```

```
# Check how many NAs are present in the first row of the dataset prior to applying the function
which(is.na(df %>%
              as_tibble() %>%
              slice(1) %>%
              unlist())) %>% # run the code till here to get the indices of the NAs
  length() 

[1] 75
```

```
df <- apply(df, 1, function(x) NA_replacer(x)) %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  data.table::transpose()

# Check how many NAs are present in the first row post applying the function
which(is.na(df %>%
              slice(1) %>%
              unlist())) %>% # run the code till here to get the indices of the NAs
  length()

[1] 175
```

```
system.time(df <- apply(df, 1, function(x) NA_replacer(x)) %>%
              as.data.table() %>%
              data.table::transpose())
user  system elapsed 
  0.216   0.002   0.220
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such for taking the time to write such a function. Unfortunately due to a typo error on my part, I was meant to say that the consecutive NAs have to be a minimum of 75 consecutive repetitions, and not 75 exactly. Looking at the function, do you think that replacing `if(length(NAs == 75))` with `if(length(NAs >= 75))` would lead to a major difference? Unfortunately I am still learning, so I'm still trying to digest every line of the function.

Comment: Actually yes. I've edited the code now to reflect what you require. Try it out!

Comment: Thank you! So I've run the code but I'm not entirely sure if it has worked. I used sum(is.na(x)) to count the total number of NAs before and after and the number remained the same. Have I input something incorrectly?

`> class(pupilData)
[1] "data.frame"
> sum(is.na(pupilData))
[1] 48408
> pupilData=NA_replacer(pupilData)
> sum(is.na(pupilData))
[1] 48408`

Note that the function was already loaded in. Apologies for the poor formatting.

Comment: Thank you again! I've run it and it definitely works, but it seems to be giving me an error when I input my dataset. Specifically, `Error in Vector[seq(NAs[1] - 50, NAs[1] - 1, 1)] <- NA : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`. My guess is that this could be due to the fact that there are inconsistent patterns of NAs in different rows of the dataframe (e.g. some begin and end with several NAs, one row even has 2000+ NAs (eye-tracking!)). I'll try clean the DF tomorrow and retry the function, thank you so much for your time and help!